# Correctly compiling and linking multiple asm files into a .vfd - for Oracle VM?

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, nasm, ld, floppy

Lately I've been wanting to get into assembly coding, just to have some experience under my belt. I decided to look into it and was getting some good results(though its simple asm), however everything is still blurry, and I would much appreciate some input from others on how to correctly build **multiple** .asm files into **.. &.. &..** to finish with a **.vfd** or a **.img** file for **Oracle VM**.

So over the past few weeks in my spare time, I've been researching around the web trying to find a working method that will enable me to:

```
1. Compile my .asm files into individual .obj files
2. Link these multiple files into one .bin
3. Place this .bin into a .vfd or .img
4. Finally ran on the Oracle VM.
```

The programs i am currently using on my **windows 7 64bit system** are:

(all through **MinGW**)

```
1. nasm   - to compile the asm to .obj / .bin files
2. ld     - to link .obj files into a .bin (I think)
3. dd     - to create a .img file from a .bin file
```

After some time of messing about I've been able to compile a **single .asm** file **into** a .bin file, and then placed it into a **.img** using **dd** (the below was from tutorials online):

(a bat file which executes these commands in the order below)

```
1. nasm -f bin -o bootloader.bin bootloader.asm  
2. dd if=bootloader.bin of=output.img count=1440
```

and then I just ran the Oracle VM which reads the output.img and displays it correctly. YAY.

Now. I've coded in Visual **c++** for some years now, and i typically use many files in single solution. I feel that when coding in asm, I should also be able to have **multiple files**. So I've read around and many use **'ld'** - a **linker** which '*joins*' .obj files into .bin files?

So I edited the above bat file to the following:

```
1a. nasm -f bin -o bootloader.bin bootloader.asm 
1b. nasm -f bin -o kernel.bin     kernel.asm 
2.  ld -o link.bin bootloader.obj kernel.obj 
3.  dd if=link.bin of=output.img  count=1440
```

The first error i got was: "cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file". After 
I Googled.. and *Googled*... and **Googled**.... and ***Googled***..... (one link to the next) and I couldn't find any other methods that worked - I just got more errors! I'm honestly lost. - I tried several different programs (eg objcopy), **lots of different parameters**,  etc.. and I haven't made too much progress. I need guidance. :)

And here is my final questions. Will **''linking''** these files together **with** ld give me the desired results **I seek**? (multiple files in one final binary file) and how can I do it **correctly** on my **windows system**?

I'm not all to in-depth with asm or these programs so **I've tried** to read up as **much as I could** before i got here. So please if you could keep the explanations nice and clear. Im sorry if its a lot to ask for, and please no grilling. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to "link" multiple flat binary files (Nasm's `-f bin` output). If we were forced to use (G)as, there's no `-f bin` output. `ld` will create a flat binary from an ELF linkable object. I think the command line is something like `ld -oformat binary -T.text=0x7C00 -o boot.bin boot.o`. I don't know if MinGW's `ld` will do it, and I don't know if it will handle multiple files. Something to try, at least...

Linking won't do you any good with your bootsector, in any case. When your computer (or VM?) boots, only the first sector is loaded - 512 bytes exactly. You'll have to provide code to load your "kernel.bin" (or "stage2.bin" from disk (or .vfd?) to a known location in memory. In order to easily find this further code, it is convenient to have it located immediately after the boot sector. You can use `cat` or `copy` (I think you'll want the `/b` option) to combine "boot.bin" and "kernel.bin" to a single file - then `dd` it to floppy (or .vfd?).

"kernel.bin" is more flexible. It can be larger than 512 bytes, and could be built from multiple object files. You'll want a flat binary, or you could provide a loader for some executable format - probably MZ, since you're still in 16-bit mode. Once you've switched to 32- (or 64-) bit Pmode, you'll probably want to arrange to load PE or ELF or whatever executable format...

Best source of information I know for this kind of thing is http://www.osdev.org - check it out, if you haven't. Happy bootin'!

Comment: Ar yes, I tried "ld -oformat binary -T.text=0x7C00 -o boot.bin boot.o" to no avail. It worked, however when i actually ran it in the virtual machine, it informed me that it was unreadable. i linked a blank file with one which works by itself, to which the output of this was obscured. (opened in msvc)

I'll defiantly try cat/copy in the next few days and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the functionality of the `include` directive.

for instance:

```
;****in kernel.asm
%include "bootloader.asm"
;... continue with kernel code
```

and compile kernel.asm as you normally would. The code in `bootloader.asm` will be executed just as if it were in `kernel.asm` where the `include` line is. This allows building a single binary from multiple asm source files.

Another way is to pre-include with

```
nasm -f bin -o kernel.bin kernel.asm -p bootloader.asm
```

Also see http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.6

and http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.17